# Converting Action Event to Mouse Event in java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, actionevent

I am using swing application i need to convert Action event into Mouse Event so how do I Convert it?
any suggestion are Welcomed

Comment: You can't.  `MouseEvent` carries with it information about the mouse, buttons, modifiers, etc, the `ActionEvent` carries none of this information and in fact, could be generated by the keyboard or programmatically.  Supply a use case for your problem, maybe we can figure out a better solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer if Mouse Event can be Convert into Action Event then vise varsa is not possible?

Comment: As I said, `MouseEvent` carries more information about then the state of the mouse then `ActionEvent`.  `ActionEvent` says something happened, `MouseEvent` says how, where and with what.  The only choice you would have is to fake all the information which might not result in desirable results. You're trying to make a mouse into an elephant

Comment: @MadProgrammer ohh then there is no way if i want to call mouse event from the component which is performing Action event is it?

Comment: The question is, why?  What are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well i have A button from which label's mouse clicked is called. i am trying to do that.

Comment: JButton has public void doClick() method you can call or you can define a method called from the button's listener and call it from the second place as well.

Comment: It would be simpler to have a method that both the action and mouse listeners could call

Comment: @MadProgrammer i took long code in action Performed. event now have to change it? :(

Comment: *"now have to change it?"*  It should take no more than 2-3 lines of code to turn the code in the `actionPerformed(..)` method into a method (ignoring white space lines).  Stop dithering about with useless strategies and just do it!